# Calculating $H_1$ in branched covering

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am studying *A quick trip to knot theory* by Fox. In section 8 the author studies branched covering. I can follow the discussion but I cannot understand how he calculates the matrix $J^{\theta\rho}$. It starts calculating the Jacobian matrix of the relations of the fundamental group and using the representation of the symmetric group ha can calculate $H_1\oplus A_{g-1}$.

In the example he gives the presentation $(x,a;a^2x=xa)$, the Jacobian of course is $J=||a^2-a \quad  1+a-x||$. Then, he gives the expression of the matrix  $J^{\theta\rho}$ as a $6\times 3$ matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}
-1 & 0 & 1 & 1 &  0 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$

how does he calculates it?